# How to automate the setting of Google as default search engine in Microsoft Edge (Chromium based) via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge, chromium

I would like to automate an operation of setting Google as a default search engine in Microsoft Edge (**Chromium based**) via PowerShell in non-corporate deployment scenario, aka as a stand-alone user.

After installation, there is bing.com.

> Currently using Version 100.0.1185.50 (Official build) (64bit version)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I thinh you can modify the corresponding registry via powershell script to achieve your requirement.

And you need to make sure your machine is joined to a Microsoft Active Directory domain, among other possible conditions.

For more details, please refer to these required group policy documents :
[Enable the default search provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#defaultsearchproviderenabled)
and
[Default search provider search URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#defaultsearchprovidersearchurl). You can find their registry path in these docs.

Comment: Will this work on Win11 Pro without Active Dictionary, or other corporate deployment scenarios?

Comment: As mentioned in the doc, if it is the case you mentioned, then this requirement will not be achieved.

Comment: For this issue, you can send feedback to relevant team to improve and refine Edge. Just press `Shift+ Alt+I` in Edge to edit your suggestion and send it.

Comment: Well,... I'm not sure what exactly should I report. Microsoft don't care about the world outside USA (Cortana, Bing, etc.), the world doesn't care about Bing. Even Microsoft engineers doesn't use Bing. Setting Google as default search engine in Edge would the single biggest step to sanity of all admins.

Comment: corresponding registry via powershell ?